# Rewrite url by using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a aspx blog website which creates a page dynamically.At the time of page creation
the unique id automatically generated it's name was generated as given below

eg:

`http://www.websitename.com/2016/f1.aspx`

`http://www.websitename.com/2016/f2.aspx`

`http://www.websitename.com/2016/f3.aspx`

How can I change the url name of the page.

Ex:(`websitename.com/2016/f2.aspx` 
to
 `websitename.com/2016/helloworld.aspx`)

`helloworld.aspx` is the blog title which I've consider to given against `f2.aspx`.
How can I replace programmatically in C# code?

Comment: `Response.Redirect("url")` should work.

Comment: sir u mistaken i just want to rewrite the url . The following example that i was given above.Anyway thanks for your compliment...

Comment: are you starting with a string and getting a string out, or are you starting with something like a HttpContext?
There are lots of ways to work with a URL depending on where you come in from. e.g. MVC does a whole thing with RouteValues, in RequestContext you can see the URL.HostName. Theres too much to cover everything in a quick reply.

If you are just dealing with strings, then maybe something like a string.Split('/'); then deal with array index 2 and join the array back together.

Comment: @keerthiraaju I guess you don't want to use javascript to do it ?

Comment: See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You can do this: `websitename.com/2016/helloworld.aspx`.

You'll need to add either a different parameter to identify `f1`, `f2` or `f3` 
like `websitename.com/2016/helloworld.aspx?PageId= f1` 
or, you can use URL like `websitename.com/2016/helloworld.aspx/f1` or
`websitename.com/2016/helloworld.aspx/f2`

Now , to achieve this (if you are using ASP.NET) need to write HTTP handler or can work in `Global.asax` as well.

**Below links will help you more:**

1. [C-SharpCorner: URL Rewriting](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net/)
2. [Codeproject: URL Rewriting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET)